# Is it possible to popUp a lottie animation View while an async Task is request

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, lottie

I have created a content view , and inside this content view I've insert a lottie animation :

I'm trying to make it a common animation view so I can use it to multiple async Task

**LoadingAnimation.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:lottie="clr-namespace:Lottie.Forms;assembly=Lottie.Forms"
             x:Class="Fit_Plans.Views.Common.LoadingAnimation">
  <ContentView.Content>
      <StackLayout>
          <lottie:AnimationView
              Grid.Column="0"
              Margin="-20"
              x:Name="LoadingAnimationView"
              Animation="loading_animation.json"

              AutoPlay="false"
              HeightRequest="160"
              WidthRequest="160"
              VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
              HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Now in my SomeView.Xaml.cs

```
 async protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            Product produits = new Product();          
            if(getListProduit ==null || getListProduit.Count<=0)
            {  
                getListProduit = await produits.loadMenuAsync(api, siteUrl);
                PopulateProductsLists(getListProduit);
            }
            base.OnAppearing();

        }
```

You can notice that I have a await asynch task :

```
getListProduit = await produits.loadMenuAsync(api, siteUrl);
```

Is it possible to make my lottie animation pop-up the animation.jason , and when the task is done close the popup? Or , what would be the best way to do such thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show lottie animation in a popup, I encourage you to use the great [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup) library. You can get it from nuget and then create a popup page in which you should add your lottie animation (the same as you did above). This way you'll be able to reuse this popup animation page.

XAML of your popup page would look similar to this:

```
<pages:PopupPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    x:Class="MyProject.MyPopupPage">
    <!--You can set an animation in the xaml file or in the csharp code behind-->
    <pages:PopupPage.Animation>
        <animations:ScaleAnimation 
            PositionIn="Center"
            PositionOut="Center"
            ScaleIn="1.2"
            ScaleOut="0.8"
            DurationIn="400"
            DurationOut="300"
            EasingIn="SinOut"
            EasingOut="SinIn"
            HasBackgroundAnimation="True"/>
    </pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <!--You can use any elements here which are extended from Xamarin.Forms.View-->
     <lottie:AnimationView
          Grid.Column="0"
          Margin="-20"
          x:Name="LoadingAnimationView"
          Animation="loading_animation.json"

          AutoPlay="true"
          HeightRequest="160"
          WidthRequest="160"
          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

[Here](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/wiki/Navigation) you can find the code to use your new popup page.

Comment: Thank you , I will read documentation and figure it out , thanks for the advice